# Not able to write Unit Tests for such methods

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, junit4

I am trying to junit test a very simple method. Something like this:

```
private SomeCarFactory someCarFactory;
private Predicate<CarRequest> isCarColorRed = carRequest -> carRequest.getCarColor() == CarTypeEnum.RED;
public List<CarResponse> post(Set<CarRequest> newCarsSet){
    // Filter the cars based on their car colors
    List<CarResponse> carResponseList = someCarFactory.getCarService(CarTypeEnum.RED).execute(filterCarsBasedOnCarType(newCarsSet, isCarColorRed));
    return carResponseList;
}

private Set<CarRequest> filterCarsBasedOnCarType(Set<CarRequest> newCarsSet, Predicate<CarRequest> predicate) {
    return newCarsSet.stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

I am using Junit4 and Mockito frameworks. I mocked the class `SomeCarFactory` and the `CarService` class which the factory class returns.

```
Set<CarRequest> redCarSet = createTestRedCars();
Set<CarRequest> blueCarSet = createTestBlueCars();
Set<CarRequest> carRequestSet = new HashSet<>();
carRequestSet.addAll(redCarSet);     
carRequestSet.addAll(blueCarSet);
Mockito.when(someCarFactory.getCarService(CarTypeEnum.RED)).thenReturn(carService);
Mockito.when(carService.execute(redCarSet)).thenReturn(someRedCarResponse);
```

The above obviously doesn't work because the `redCarSet Object` used in above `when` is different from the object that is being created when the method `filterCarsBasedOnCarType` is being called.

How do I unit test the `post` method ?

Comment: `redCarSet` does not have to be the same object as the argument to `execute`, it just has to be `equal`. That being set, you may want to separate the filtering and the `post` into their own classes. It's a better design and makes testing easier

Comment: That's interesting...let me try it out